# Append to future DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append

Im trying to append text to a DOM element that is adde dynamically. My code is

```
$(document).on("ready", "#slides2 .slidesjs-pagination-item", function(event){
    $("#slides2 .slidesjs-pagination-item a").prepend("Image ");
    $("#slides2 .slidesjs-pagination-item a").append(" of 30");
});
```

I want to add the text to `.slidesjs-pagination-item a` which is created by a slideshow script.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

```
i = e("<ul>", { 
     "class": "slidesjs-pagination"
 }).appendTo(n); 
 e.each(new Array(this.data.total), function (t) { 
     var n, r;
     n = e("<li>", { 
         "class": "slidesjs-pagination-item" 
     }).appendTo(i); 
     r = e("<a>", { 
         href: "#", 
         "data-slidesjs-item": t, 
         html: t + 1 
     }).appendTo(n);
```

is the slideshow source where the element is added. How would i add to this?

Comment: pretty simple...can't append to an element that doesn't exist....do it when it does exist. You need to work within the API of the slideshow script

Comment: And how would I go about that? From my understanding .on should affect future and exsisting elements...

Comment: read the slideshow script docs...use events exposed in the API that give you access. If script doesn't have features you need...use another one that does

Comment: `.on` doesn't work like that, `.on` is for **event** delegation. In your case, it's simple. Look in your code for when you create that element, and after that, do your appending

Comment: Ok, my knowledge of jquery/javascript is very limited so I find it hard to understand how to append within the slideshow script.

Comment: `i = e("<ul>", {
                    "class": "slidesjs-pagination"
                }).appendTo(n);
                e.each(new Array(this.data.total), function (t) {
                    var n, r;
                    n = e("<li>", {
                        "class": "slidesjs-pagination-item"
                    }).appendTo(i);
                    r = e("<a>", {
                        href: "#",
                        "data-slidesjs-item": t,
                        html: t + 1
                    }).appendTo(n);`

Comment: See the [`edit`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20296361/edit) button below your question?

Comment: The above is where the element is added but im not sure how to add to it

Comment: Take the time to cleanly indent your code before posting it.

Comment: Its indented now, thanks blue